# Application of associative property in the proof of finding the solution of the equation ax=b.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, associativity

I am trying to find the solution for the equation $ax=b$ where $a,b \in G$ and $G$ is a group with respect to the operation, multiplication. This is what I gathered from different books
$$ax=b$$ 
pre multiply both sides with $a^{-1}$.
$$(a^{-1})ax=(a^{-1})b$$
Then it says according to associative property $aa^{-1}=e$.
$$ex=(a^{-1})b$$
$$x=(a^{-1})b.$$ 
But the thing that I don't understand is the step where the associative property is applied above because according to associative property(w.r.t multiplication)

$$ \forall a,b,c \in G  , a(bc)=(ab)c$$ and in this case we know that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ belongs to $G$ but $x$ does not. So how can one apply associative property in such a situation. Please elucidate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why $x$ does not belong to $G$ ? If so, what does it mean to multiply it by $a$ to get $b \in G$ ?

Comment: $x$ belongs in $G$, in any other case it would not make sense to solve the equation.

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I too know that x ∈ G intuitively and after finding the solution i.e (a^-1)b one can prove that it belongs to G by closure property but abstract algebra is all about theorizing the basic concepts we know. So isn't there any method to prove x ∈ G before using the associativity there ?

Comment: @Azif00 To check if the equation has any solutions if yes then does it belong to the same set

Comment: You want to know if $ax=b$ has any solutions.  Well try $x=(a^{-1})b$ and you will find that is a solution.  Now you want to know if it is the _unique_ solution.  If $a,x,b$ all lie in some set for which multiplication is defined as usual (meaning that it is associative) then yes.  If you can define your own "multiplication" that does not have to be associative then "no" because I will invent a new symbol $\ddot\smile$ that is not in any group but I will define a non-associative "multiplication" that says $a\ddot\smile = b$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion about whether $x$ lies in the group was addressed in the comments.

The associativity step that you're looking for comes right after you left-multiply by $a^{-1}$ to get
$$(a^{-1})(ax) = a^{-1}b.$$
On the left you need to apply associativity to see that:
$$a^{-1}(ax) = (a^{-1} a)x = ex.$$

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So you have $ax = b$.  They are both different ways of writing the same element.  I will refer to that element as $THEELEMENT$.  We have $b =THEELEMENT$ and $ax = THEELMENT$.

Now if we multiply $THEELEMENT$ by $a^{-1}$ we get a second element $a^{-1}\cdot THEELEMENT$.  I will refer to this as $THEOTHERELEMENT$.

So $THEOTHERELEMENT = a^{-1}\cdot THEELEMENT = a^{-1}\cdot (ax) = a^{-1}\cdot b$

Now the text is going to make the claim that

$THEOTHERELEMENT = a^{-1}\cdot (ax) = (a^{-1}a)\cdot x$.

But why can we say that if do $ax$ first to get $THEELEMENT$ and then do $a^{-1}THEELEMENT$ that that will be the same as doing $(a^{-1}a)$ first and then doing $(a^{-1}a)\cdot x$ to get the same thing?

Well, *THAT* is where associativity comes in.

$a^{-1}(ax) = (a^{-1}a) x$ by associativity

And so

$a^{-1}(ax) = a^{-1}b$

$(a^{-1}a)x = a^{-1}b$

$ex = a^{-1}b$

$x = a^{-1}b$.

The thing is this was *so* intuitively obvious you didn't even bother to write down your terms with parenthesis to tell us what order we were doing them in.  Why not? Because you didn't think it mattered.  And why didn't you think it mattered?  Because it *doesn't* because of associativity.

But if you *didn't* have associativity it *would* matter and would *have* to write $a^{-1}(ax) =a^{-1}b$.  Writing $(a^{-1})ax$ would both be unclear because you didn't write the order, and *wrong* if you assume tthe order is left to right$.